# binding forms to a recordset which is opening a table on local db

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to show data in a recordset by binding it to a form in ms-access 2010. recordset is opening a query over currentdb (not external). Here's my code, its executing on the Form_Load() event:

```
Dim rs as Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Employee.* FROM Employee", dbOpenDynaset)
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

The form in my opinion is not binding to the recordset. I tried searching this for over a day but though I'm setting my controlsource properties properly I cannot figure out why nothing is getting displayed.
My recordset as I said is NOT and ADODB recordset!! its just a recordset object grabbing data from the local database (which has linked tables).

p.s: I tried executing the same in the Form on Open event but that caused ms-access  to crash

Comment: How is your form set up? Is it a datasheet, a normal form with fields, or is there a subform which will display the records?

Comment: its a continuous form with fields. Although I'm open to display this as a datasheet as well.

Comment: I'm sure using a continuous form is fine, just have to figure out how to make it work :)  How are you binding your controls to the fields?

Comment: using the code:
Me.TxtBox1.ControlSource = "EmpName"

the above line seems to be working if I bind the form directly from the properties box. but since my query is very complicated and with a dynamically generated temporary tables, I need to do it in vba with a recordset that I can easily modify.

Comment: I hear you, I've run into that problem before and had to solve it the same way. What error or behavior are you seeing that lets you know that it didn't work?  For example, does the form open, does it then display multiple rows, are those rows empty or do they have data, etc etc - where does the failure occur?

Comment: The fields do not display any records. Its just one row of blank fields (current query returns over 500 records). The form opens fine (even from a button on another form).

Comment: Try a super simple query just to make sure you can get it to work at all (perhaps where or how you are assigning the form's recordset is upsetting Access :P).  `"SELECT 1 AS test"`

Comment: nope..that didn't work either  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I led you astray... while `"SELECT 1 AS test"` is a perfectly valid query, forms don't seem to like it.  Instead, try this.

Create a table called "tblTest", add a single Text field "test" and add a few items.

Create a blank continuous form and call it "frmTest".  Add a single textbox control and call it "txtTest".

Add a Form_Open event code builder and define it like so:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblTest")
    Set Me.Recordset = rs
    Me.txtTest.ControlSource = "test"
End Sub
```

Does that work?

Comment: hey amazingly it worked after restarting access. The simple query is working on my form as well. I'll work on the complex one and see if that works. it seems the parameter Cancel as Integer was the key to resolve this issue. Its now working on only the form_open event but not form_load.

Comment: Glad to hear you tracked it down!